# получение содержимого тега в php

Tags: php, html

я изучаю серверный php и хочу получить содержимое тега `<div contenteditable="true" name="div"></div>`

Как мне это реализовать?
Я пробовал через `if (isset ($_POST["div"]))`, но программа не работает.

Comment: Добавьте подробностей. Откуда вы берёте (собираетесь брать) теги?

Comment: в POST попадают поля формы <form>, либо аякс запрос. инпут поля формы это сами input или textarea. ваш див с contenteditable в форму сам по себе не попадет. Вам нужно либо аякс отправлять взяв данные из дива, либо копировать контент в скрытые поля формы и ее отправлять.